# Format specific text within a cell with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

When I use Excel it allows me to set specific words within a cell to **bold** or *italic* or even change the text size.

Is there a way of doing this in VBA?

I have two cells with text. One cell contains a list of words which I separated into an array. The other cell contains a few sentences.

I want to write a macro that highlights all words from cell 1 in cell 2.

My idea was to use the array and InStr to search for the position of my words in cell 2. Once found I wanted to split cell 2, format one word an put everything back together.

Maybe this is possible via Word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer could be found here:
[excel vba: make part of string bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295380/excel-vba-make-part-of-string-bold)

Specifically,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "name/A/date" & Chr(10) & "name/B/date" & Chr(10) & "name/C/date"
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=25, Length:=4).Font
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
End With
```