# Bold the last line of text in a multi-line cell

Tags: excel, vba

I found this similar question on here ([excel vba: make part of string bold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10295380/7228018)), but I'd like to know how to tweak it to where the only the last line of every cell in a given column is bolded.  Is this possible?

Short summary:  I have a file with 2 columns where updates are stored with a corresponding date of the update.  Here's an example, where all of this is typed in one cell:

```
12/15 - A meeting was held on 11/21 to discuss alternative solutions
12/22 - The field is going to be created at the account level
12/29 - The field is built in TEST environment, ready for operations testing
01/05 - Functionality confirmed; ready to move into PROD
```

In this example, I need the last update line, "01/05 - Functionality confirmed; ready to move into PROD" to be bolded.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Is there a way to update this so that it only bolds the cell in column E of that row if column L is not blank (meaning there was no updated note entered)? Otherwise, it moves on to the next row. I have the following code, but I'm constantly getting a data type mismatch error 13. Also, I'm probably missing some code as well.

```
Sub BoldLastLine1()
Dim p As Long
Dim r As Range

For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L100")
    If Len(Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 12).Value)) <> 0 Then

        p = InStrRev(r.Value, vbLf)
        If p > 0 Then
            With r.Characters(p + 1, Len(r.Value) - p).Font
                .Bold = True
                .Size = 16
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox ("Updates Completed.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the data in separate rows? Multi-line cells are notoriously tricky when trying to manipulate.  If you do need VBA, what have you tried? You can put the cell's text in a variable, loop through that to find the last instance of `-` and work from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the last `vbLf` in the cell, and bold everything after that:

```
Sub BoldLastLine()
    Dim p As Long
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B10")
        p = InStrRev(r.Value, vbLf)
        If p > 0 Then
            r.Characters(p + 1, Len(r.Value) - p).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked like a freakin' charm!  Sorry for the late reply, but I had to shift my focus to other projects before I was able to test this.

Comment: Is there a way to update this so that it only bolds the cell in column E of that row if column L is not blank (meaning there was no updated note entered)?  Otherwise, it moves on to the next row.  I have the following code, but I'm constantly getting a data type mismatch error 13.  Also, I'm probably missing some code as well: