# Change colors specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet as below,

[image]

and I would like to give color change and bold change for specific positions that defined another columns like below.

[image]

```
Position1 : 1,2,3,10
Position2 : 5,6,7,8
```

So Change blue color for position 1,2,3,10.
And Change Red Color for position 5,6,7,8

Does anyone has good idea to make a function?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618121/change-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-cell) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small sub that will help you get started. Assuming your `position1` value is in `A2`, `position2` value is in `B2` and `Example` is in `C2`.

You can modify it to cover bigger range.

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim text As String
    Dim p1, p2 As Variant

    p1 = Split(Range("A2").Value, ",")
    p2 = Split(Range("B2").Value, ",")
    text = Range("C2").Value

    For i = LBound(p1) To UBound(p1)
        Cells(2, 3).Characters(p1(i), 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
    Next

    For i = LBound(p2) To UBound(p2)
        Cells(2, 3).Characters(p2(i), 1).Font.Color = vbRed
    Next

End Sub
```