# How to vary the format within cells (i.e. italicise some words and not others) in excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros, formatting

Could anyone help with adding a macro in excel for varying the formatting within each cell in a column (variable number of entries up to about 5000).

I need to have plant names correctly formatted:

Italise: genus, species, subspecies, or variety

But not italise the words: subsp., var., x, f. aff. or any words within quotation marks ''

i.e. *Olea europaea* subsp. *cuspidata* or *Malus domestica* 'Golden Delicious'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax for specifying which characters in a cell you want to italicise is straightforward:

```
Range("I4").FormulaR1C1 = "Malus domestica 'Golden Delicious'"
Range("I4").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=16).Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
Range("I4").Characters(Start:=16, Length:=19).Font.FontStyle = "Italic"
```

Just a matter of modifying to suit your application, i.e. figuring out which characters in the string need to be italicised. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, but every cell is different so what I need is one code which italicises all cell content except a defined list of words

Comment: That's where you come in :) Your mission is to write code that loops over all applicable cells, and implements the logic you desire to determine where to start and end the italic sections.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to format only some of the characters inside the cell, you could use a regular expression (regexp) instead of conditional formatting.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for an excellent how-to by user `Portland Runner`.

Also, look at user the answer from `brettdj` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618121/change-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-cell), who fumbled out how to only format parts of the cell value.

As for your task:

```
Sub FormatMyApples()

    ' Format keywords that are NOT wrapped in single quotes
    FormatRegExpItalic _
        "[^'](Olea europaea|cuspidata|Malus domestica|Golden Delicious)[^']" _
        , ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End Sub
```

And here's sub for the actual formatting

```
Private Sub FormatRegExpItalic( _
ByVal pattern As String, ByRef range As Variant)

    Dim RegMC As Object
    Dim RegM As Object
    Dim cell As Object

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern

        For Each cell In range
            If .test(cell.Value) Then
                Set RegMC = .Execute(cell.Value)
                For Each RegM In RegMC
                    cell.Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.FontStyle = "Italic"
                Next
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```