# Format only the fragment of text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change **format of a part of** a number-like content in a cell. For example:

In =1400 & "(∆"& -345 &")", i want only "-345" to be red. -> more or less it's going to be the same number of chars from right.

Conditional Formatting along VBA solutions are welcome :)

Edit - It should be working on formulas i.e. both '1400' and '-345' are formulas, not values

Comment: You will need to parse the characters then... one by one... and detect which characters need formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of certain characters in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618121/change-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-cell)

Comment: @braX I have checked the link you attached, but unfortunetly when I use it on something like =1400&" ("&-345&")" the macro  treats every char as numeric. 

But anyway I got some idea on  what should i do. Thanks!

Comment: Is this always at the same position from the right? And always these 4 characters?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, it can work this way. I might do any further fitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if it's always at the same position from the right and always 4 characters, then please try:

[image]

```
With Range("A1")
    .Characters(.Characters.Count - 8, 4).Font.Color = vbRed
End With
```

[image]

Using the second parameter we can specify the length which in your case is 4 characters. That way you won't have to parse characters one by one to format them. For more information please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters)

Would you need to find the position of `-` from the right, then use [`InstrRev`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function). This would substitute `.Characters.Count - 8` as a starting position.

---

**Edit:**

Through the comments it became clear your are actually working with formulas based on other cells. Since you can't really change the font color within a formula, you could hide the actual formula and add a change event to the worksheet. A very basic example could be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:D2")) Is Nothing Then
    With Range("B2")
        .Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
        .Characters(Len(.Value) - Len(.Offset(, 2).Value), Len(.Offset(, 2).Value)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image]

In fact, if you go this route, you could also decide to actually remove the actuall formula alltogether and construct the text to format through VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:D2")) Is Nothing Then
    With Range("B2")
        .Value = .Offset(, 1).Value & "(" & ChrW(8710) & .Offset(, 2).Value & ")"
        .Characters(Len(.Value) - Len(.Offset(, 2).Value), Len(.Offset(, 2).Value)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't checked, but wouldn't this only work on static text in a cell and not the result of a formula?  It's 8 characters in the formula, but 5 in the result.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I assumed the formula is static text in my example that's true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm getting "Unable to get Count property of Characters class" error

Comment: ^ Which is the cause that you are probably working with formulas? =)

Comment: Would you be okay with changing the formula into a value (text) first? @Sztywny

Comment: Well, you can't change the color of characters within a formula. However, what if you hide this column of formulas, then have a second column with static text that would change based on the hidden column. The above macro would then work again.... I'll update the question if you are interested