# you need a macro - select only those symbols that have a red color

Tags: excel

how to write a macro for excel - it is necessary to select only those symbols that have a red color in one cell, increase them to 14 font, underline them and make them bold, and leave the other symbols in the same cell in black. Thank you.

```
Sub FormatSelectedCells()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            cell.Font.Size = 14
            cell.Font.Bold = True
            cell.Font.Underline = True
        Else
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            cell.Font.Size = 11
            cell.Font.Bold = False
            cell.Font.Underline = False
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

changes the entire cell

```
Sub IncreaseRedFont()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            cel.Font.Size = 14
            cel.Font.Bold = True
            cel.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

changes the entire cell

And it is necessary to change only one word, which is red

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, post a data example and expected output

Comment: [Change color of certain characters in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618121/change-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-cell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of certain characters in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618121/change-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-cell)